# Fredhopper Installation on Linux server

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper, linux

I need to install Fredhopper on Linux environment. As I am beginner to Linux as well as for Fredhopper, looking for some document or content for the installation process which can guide me step by step.
Any reference will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will find all the details of fredhopper installation in the below link -

https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter [password required]

Comment: You can ask Customer Support for a login to the learning center

Comment: @Dylan,Sayantan,Nuno:- First of all Thanks for the response. As per the document, a dedicated user named "fredhopper" is required to perform all the task. But i have only Superuser in Linux. Can't i use super user in Linux for all such operations.

Comment: Hi Sumit, I don't have any idea regarding the restriction of using superuser  in fredhopper installation. But I think it is best practice to use the dedicated user for it. In our project we are also using dedicated user called "fredhopper".

Comment: @Sayantan:- Is it for Linux environment in your case?

Comment: Yes we are also using the Linux box for fredhopper

Comment: As per the Fredhopper learning center, Fredhopper 7.5 requires the Sun/Oracle Java Standard Edition Development Kit version 7, 64bit (JDK1.7). Can we use JDK1.8 for Fredhopper 7.5 or not?